# Unexpected error after comparing strings in android

Tags: android, logic, string-comparison

I'm currently trying to construct a method where the system compare two strings and if they are the same an intent is fired. This is code i'm using right now, it should be pretty self-explanatory:

```
String string 1 = ("Text 1");

String string 2 = EditText.getText().toString();

if(((string 1)).equals(string 2)) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
} else {}
```

The error I'm getting is the following (This code is inside "MainActivity"):
There is no applicable constructor to '(com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.(anonymous), java.lang.Class)'

I'm not really sure what this means so if someone would enlighten me that would be appreciated :)

Comment: Guess you're new to Java, it might be best to read up on it first... just saying :)

Comment: Why should I post the entire class code? If I delete this segment I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Chances are you wrote above code in the body of your class, looking at the error you're getting, or some other place you're not supposed to write it. In stead, you'll probably need to move it into a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need parentheses around string1's value during initialization, and hopefully your EditText in string2 actually contains a value derived form "R.find statement"

See if this helps:

```
String string1 = "Text 1";

String string2 = EditText.getText().toString();

if(string1.equals(string2)) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
} else {}
```

You should also follow up on MH's advice and make sure your method is properly defined.

Answer (score 1):

Should that not be

```
String string1 = ...
String string2 = ...

if (string1.equals(string2)) {
```

note the lack of spaces...